# Django query to get all formset images belonging to a particular object via foreign key relationship

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
def TrainerDashView(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
     return redirect('accounts:index')
else:
 page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
 notifications = Notification.objects.filter(receiver= request.user,task__is_verified=False)
 count = Notification.objects.filter(receiver = request.user).count()
 tasks = Task.objects.filter(student__mentor=request.user,is_verified=False)


 paginator = Paginator(tasks,1)
 try:
     tasklist = paginator.page(page)
 except PageNotAnInteger:
     tasklist = paginator.page(1)
 except EmptyPage:
     tasklist = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
 context={
    'notifications':notifications,
    'trainer':request.user,
    'tasks': tasklist,

     }
 return render(request,'mentor.html',context)
```

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
 level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 todo = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 content = models.TextField()
 timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
 datestamp = models.DateField( auto_now=True)
 like 
 =models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user_likes',blank=True)
is_verified=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('student:task-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
objects = PostManager()

@property
def comments(self):
    instance = self
    qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
    return qs

@property
def get_content_type(self):
    instance = self
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
    return content_type


class Images(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(Task, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image')
```

Im using formsets to connect 3 images to a particular task.I want to display the 3 images for the task in template.The tasks are displayed as a list with pagination ,1 task per page. How do i get all the 3 images and display for a particular task? Confused about the query to use !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pagee = request.GET.get('page')
  if pagee == None:
      pagess=1

  else:
      pagess=int(pagee)

 print("PAGE NUMBER",pagess)
 try:
  images = Images.objects.filter(post=tasks[pagess-1])
 except KeyError:
     raise TypeError('Index error')
```

I found a solution .By getting the current page number i could give it as the index of the tasks array and get the images correctly !